# Is it possible to get the most popular pages using REST?

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I want to show a list on our homepage of the most popular pages in our site collection. Is there a way of accessing this information using REST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ViewsLifetime and ViewsRecent metadata returned from http://site/subsite/_api/search/query (such as http://site/subsite/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x010100C568*'). No views is a null value.

(in JSON the return looks like)

```
20:  {
__metadata: {
type: "SP.KeyValue"
}-
Key: "ViewsLifeTime"
Value: "246"
ValueType: "Edm.Int64"
}-
21:  {
__metadata: {
type: "SP.KeyValue"
}-
Key: "ViewsRecent"
Value: "98"
ValueType: "Edm.Int64"
}
```

Comment: Where did you get ContentTypeId:0x010100C568* from?

Comment: That's just the default starting prefix for a page content type. Its just as an example of the search functionality. You can get a the content type ID's from Powershell, SP Designer or by going to Site Settings > Content Types and looking at the shortcuts. You could search by most any tag available in the metadata (name, title, author, etc). Microsoft has their API syntax reference <a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396">here</a>