# How to get top hit count pages programatically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone help me how to get Top pages by Hit Count form my site collection?

In SharePoint 2010 it was easy. CSOM, REST, jsom, powershell methods also acceptable.

Comment: Can you point to the easy of doing this with PowerShell in SharePoint 2010 as I need this functionality - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three excellent sites with step-by-step instructions for what you want:

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-Most-Visited-Sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-SharePoint-2013-Web-Analytics

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/28/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

[Is it possible to get the most popular pages using REST?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137678/is-it-possible-to-get-the-most-popular-pages-using-rest)